# Show that there do not exist functions $f(x)$ and $g(h)$ such that $\cos{(x + h)} − \cos{x} = f(x)g(h)$ for all $x, h \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Show that there do not exist functions $f(x)$ and $g(h)$ such that $\cos{(x + h)} − \cos{x} = f(x)g(h)$ for all $x, h \in \mathbb{R}$.

So far, I have tried following the same logic as this similar problem (part b):

[Prove No Functions f and g Satisfy f(x)g(y)= x + y](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Z3itbjOtix-23RBbQcT_4IK3d9szs3E/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the solution to that problem, which I cannot quite understand.

[Solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QP1R7ERUGsD8wo2x1OP8CGEpKPaIrFU3/view?usp=sharing)

I don't understand how $\frac{xy}{g(0) f(0)} = xy$ is yielded.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining what you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. Isolated problem statements tend to give the wrong impression in this regard, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Blue is totally correct. Perhaps a very general thing is to try to get rid of one variable one side completely and prove that the other side is not independent of this variable. This would yield a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing by $h$ and letting $h \to 0$ we get $-\sin x =f(x) g'(0)$. Thus $f(x)=c \sin x$ where $c=-\frac  1 {g'(0)}$.  Now put $x=0$ to get $\cos h -1= 0$ which is a contradiction. .

Comment: I understand how you got -sin(x) on the left side but how did you get f(x) g'(0)? f(x) * g(h) / h may become f(x) * (g(h) - 0) / h but you can't say it equals f(x) * (g(h) - g(0)) / h or f(x) * g'(0) because that assumes g(0) = 0

Comment: @AlexanderBullen Putting $h=0$ gives $0=f(x)g(0)$. What happens if $g(0) \neq 0$?

Comment: Ok, I understand that step. But what is the contradiction? f(0)g(h) = cosh - 1. Therefore, f(0)g(0) = cos0 - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0. Do I compare this with another computation of f(0)g(0) ?

Comment: @AlexanderBullen Why are you putting $h=0$ at  the end? Put $h=\frac {\pi} 2$ for example to get a  contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\cos (x+h)-\cos x=f(x)g(h)$ for all $x,h.$

Then $-2\cos x=f(x)g(\pi)$ and $-\sin x-\cos x=f(x)g(\pi/2).$

Hence $$-2g(\pi/2)\cos x=f(x)g(\pi)g(\pi/2)=(-\sin x -\cos x)g(\pi).$$  Since $g(\pi)\ne 0$ (else $-2\cos x=f(x)g(\pi)=0$ for all $x),$ we have $$\sin x=(-1+2g(\pi/2)/g(\pi))\cos x$$ which  is false when $x=\pi/2.$

Addendum: Perhaps simpler, consider $x=\pi/2$ in the 2nd sentence above. Then $0=f(\pi/2)g(\pi)$ and $0\ne -1=f(\pi/2)g(\pi/2),$ so $g(\pi)=0.$ But then $-2\cos x=f(x)g(\pi)=0$ for all $x.$